# PHP 5.6 Mcrypt x64 and MIT Scheme not compatible?

Tags: php, ubuntu, 64-bit, scheme, apt-get

I have PHP 5.6 `PHP 5.6.17-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli)` installed currently, on Mint 17.2 x64 (Cinnamon). If I try to install `mit-scheme`, I get:

`sudo apt-get install mit-scheme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common libjs-codemirror libjs-jquery-cookie libjs-jquery-event-drag
  libjs-jquery-metadata libjs-jquery-mousewheel libjs-jquery-tablesorter
  libjs-jquery-ui php-gettext
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libmcrypt4:i386 libmhash2:i386 libpq5:i386
Suggested packages:
  libmcrypt-dev:i386 mcrypt:i386 mit-scheme-dbg:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libmcrypt-dev libmcrypt4 mcrypt php5-mcrypt phpmyadmin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmcrypt4:i386 libmhash2:i386 libpq5:i386 mit-scheme:i386
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 5 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,668 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,040 kB disk space will be freed.`

Seems the problem is between `libmcrypt4` and `libmcrypt4:i386`. Is there not an x64 version of Scheme, or a way to keep those two `mcrypt` versions from interfering with each other? Best (of poor) options looks like installing Scheme in a 32bit virtual machine. Another option is compiling PHP from a 32 bit source, if that is possible on a 64bit machine. Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up building mit-scheme from source outside my package manager on gentoo two years ago and it's still working. I would suggest you install mit-scheme from the source (https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/liarc-build.html) or update to jessie, as jessie includes an amd64 version, whereas wheezy does not. https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mit-scheme

So within wheezy the answer is not. However I know for sure you can compile 9.0.1 and later to a 64-bit target.

```
file /usr/local/bin/mit-scheme-x86-64
/usr/local/bin/mit-scheme-x86-64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't' catch Mint, I just assumed Debian. However you should be able to look through the package pages to see which if any version supports the amd64 package. My suggestion is still to compile if you can't update. Theres a small chance the jessie packages will work in mint.

Comment: I downloaded the debian package directly from the debian.org link you provided, and it installed and runs no problem. Sometimes Debian packages work all the way down, glad it did this time! Thanks for the tip!